# If you want to fix bug between f5 and ctrl + F5 on Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: memory, directx, stack-overflow, directx-9, directx-10

When I build my project and run game, I get this error always.

```
  Unhandled exception at 0x76fb2073 in Screen.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000338 or sometimes 0x00000000.
```

When I debug this error, I can see the free.c source file.

.....

```
        else    //  __active_heap == __SYSTEM_HEAP
#endif  /* _WIN64 */
        {
            retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);
            **if (retval == 0)                  // Here, error occured**
            {
                errno = _get_errno_from_oserr(GetLastError());
            }
        }
}
```

......

When I trace this debug path, I found that error occured on this line on my screen.cpp file.

```
if(FAILED(D3DXLoadMeshFromX(szName, D3DXMESH_SYSTEMMEM,
        m_pd3dDevice, &pAdjacencyBuffer,
        &pD3DXMtrlBuffer, NULL, &pMesh->dwNumMaterial,
        &pMesh->pMesh)))
```

I can't know why this error occur all time when I run this game.

Need your help!

Oh, Yes.

I forgoted one thing.

When I run project by press key-F5, whether it runs on full screen or window mode, game works good.

Only When I press Ctrl + F5, the error occur.

Comment: The code is probably trying to de-reference a NULL pointer.

Comment: Well, parameter's value is like this.
szName: "hole.map"

Comment: m_pd3dDevice is 0x34847302
pAdjacencyBuffer is NULL
pD3DXMtrlBuffer is NULL
pMesh->dwNumMaterial is NULL
pMesh->pMesh is NULL

Comment: But when I run this on window mode or press f5, then the error not occur!

Comment: Only press F5, whether window mode or full screen mode, the project works very well

Comment: I just made a chat room. Let's take it there instead of comments.

Comment: Well, actually, m_pd3dDevice is not null and szName is not null then D3DXLoadMeshFromX function must succes. Isn't it?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5274/room-for-s-l-barth-and-btagtiger

Comment: Oh, I can't know the reason, Please help me! I must fix this error during 1 day.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5279/discussion-between-btagtiger-and-s-l-barth)

Comment: Well, I didn't fixed it yet. Please help me. Is nobody who can help me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5283/discussion-between-btagtiger-and-s-l-barth)

Comment: The reason why you are seeing different behavior between F5 and Ctrl-F5 is that when you run under the Debugger, Visual Studio does some things for you:
In particular it will initialize some of your local variables to default values, it will add padding to memory allocations, etc.

The easiest way to debug this kind of issues is to add logging so that you can learn what is uninitialized.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've solved this problem my self.
I build my file as debug file.
Then it works good.